How to solve for an Modulo Arithmetic for base with large exponent and modulo
The modulo function is as follows:
$\big((13 ^ m) \mod p + (37 ^ m) \mod p\big) \mod p$
The known values are $p$ being $177$ digits long as well as $2$ results from this function being:
$$\big((13 ^ m) \mod p + (37 ^ m) \mod p\big) \mod p = a$$
$$\big((13 ^ {m-1}) \mod p + (37 ^ {m-1}) \mod p\big) \mod p = b$$
$a$ and $b$ are $166$ digit integers which I know the value of
Given this problem how can I find the value of m?
What I have tried after researching on Modulo Arithmetic is that I can simplify
$\big((13 ^ m) \mod p + (37 ^ m) \mod p\big) \mod p$
to
$(13 ^ m + 37 ^ m) \mod p$
but that's all to my lead I am unsure how to continue from this.
These are the values of $p$ and their results:
$p = 396430433566694153228963024068183195900644000015629930982017434859080008533624204265038366113052353086248115602503012179807206251960510130759852727353283868788493357310003786807$
$\big((13 ^ m) \mod p + (37 ^ m) \mod p\big) \mod p = 67077340815509559968966395605991498895734870241569147039932716484176494534953008553337442440573747593113271897771706973941604973691227887232994456813209749283078720189994152242$
$\big((13 ^ {m-1}) \mod p + (37 ^ {m-1}) \mod p) \mod p = 88952575866827947965983024351948428571644045481852955585307229868427303211803239917835211249629755846575548754617810635567272526061976590304647326424871380247801316189016325247$

This is hard to read.  here is a good tutorial on formatting for this site.

This is my first time using StackExchange, I will take note about it. Thanks!

If we let $x=13^{m-1}\bmod p$ and $y=37^{m-1}\bmod p$, then we have
$$13x+37y\equiv a$$
$$x+y\equiv b$$
which we can easily solve for $x$ and $y$. So we know $13^m=13x$ and $37^m=37y$.
Deducing the value of $m$ from the value of $13^m\bmod p$ is an instance of the Discrete Logarithm Problem, which unfortunately is thought to be computationally hard. So I'm afraid nobody knows how to solve your problem.
Two caveats:

Perhaps somebody at the NSA does know how to take discrete logarithms modulo a large prime, but they haven't published their algorithm.
We actually know more than just $13^m\bmod p$; we also know $37^m\bmod p$. I can't see how this would make things any easier, but you never know!


perhaps there is a way we can compare the 2 values a and b?

Like I said: I can't see how.

feels very similar to dh key exchange, where we could assume the value of a and b to be the public key
